# How do I play a sound in Powerpoint everytime the user visits the slide?

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint

In Powerpoint, if a slide is reloaded the sound won't start again.
This means, that if the user goes to the next slide and then the previous, the sound won't be played again.

This is a problem, as I have speak telling the user what to do in every slide.

I use Powerpoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

**The Usual Answer**

The usual answer is to create a blank slide with an automatic transition of zero seconds and put it before the slide in question. Hyperlink to this slide and the animations will be reset before an instant transition to the "real" slide.

Usually a button is placed on the "real" slide to hyperlink back to the original slide. If you are visiting the animated slide from several different slides as you might in a quiz then a button to hyperlink back can be a problem (remember the "last slide viewed" was the dummy slide NOT the original source so a button to "last slide viewed is not going to work).

**Another Solution**

Create a "Custom Show" consisting of just the slide(s) to be hyperlinked to, you can use one slide or several.

To create a custom show Slide Show > Custom shows > New

Make hyperlinks to "Custom Show" making sure that "Show and return" in ticked. Giving the custom shows suitable names will make tracking what the do easier.You will not need a button to return to the "last slide viewed" as this will happen automatically when you get to the end of the custom show. (If you DO want to add a button it should hyperlink to "End Show". Do not be tempted to use a "go to slide x") hyperlink as this will leave multiple custom shows running.

Each time the custom show is visited the animations will be reset and play again.

Comment: That's exactly what I already did. Did you even read my problem? I can't get the sound to play AGAIN. I can make it play in the start. But when the slide is revisited, the sound won't play again.

Comment: I just edited my post, read it again, I hope that will solve your problems. Best regards.